# Face loop duplicating deformed

Tags: modeling, loop

The selected face loop is the one I want to duplicate.
[image: screenshot of selected face loop]

When I duplicate this face loop, it is deformed in three faces in oval shape.
[image]

As you can see, the two faces have oval shaped ends and one is completely disconnected from others.
I have Bevel and Subsurf modifiers active. I haven't applied them yet since it will complicate the shape of the wall. I tried applying all transforms, and seems like it does not have any effect on it.
Why is this occuring? and how can I fix this?
Why is this error

Comment: It appears that you have some modifier(s) applied to the object, perhaps "Subdivision"?  Please include a screen image of the modifiers, completely expanded.

Comment: This happens for disconnected edges. Use Merge by Distance.